# Como paso una variable con saltos de linea?

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia a todos.
Me pueden ayudar de favor a encontrar esta solucion: No puedo enviar saltos de linea desde un formulario que pasa por javascript y al final a whatsapp. He intentado muchas maneras con \n y los saltos de javascript pero no logro hacerlo.

Aqui paso los datos de la variable que se muestra antes de ser enviado a whatsapp en un formulario que es la vista previa

```
<div class="box-input">
       <     <span style = "color: #9b9b9b;">Pedido</span>
             <input name="pedido" id="pedido" type="text" value='<?php echo $productoo;?>' readonly="readonly" required>
          </div>
```

Aqui paso el pedido a whatsapp

```
    formulario.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        buttonSubmit.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>'
        buttonSubmit.disabled = true
        setTimeout(() => `introducir el código aquí`{
            let nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value
            let apellidos = document.querySelector('#apellidos').value
            let email = document.querySelector('#email').value
            var pedido = document.querySelector('#pedido').value
            let total = document.querySelector('#total').value
            let envio = document.querySelector('#envio').value
            let mensaje = 'send?phone=' + telefono + '&text=*_Pedido_*%0A*Nombre:*%0A' + nombre + '%0A*Apellido:*%0A' + apellidos + '%0A*Direccion:*%0A' + email + '%0A*Pedido:*%0A' + pedido + '%0A*Costo de envio:*%0A' + envio + '%0A*Total:*%0A' + total + ''
            if(isMobile()) {
                window.open(urlMobile + mensaje, '_blank')
            }else{
                window.open(urlDesktop + mensaje, '_blank')
            }
            buttonSubmit.innerHTML = '<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> Enviar WhatsApp'
            buttonSubmit.disabled = false
        }, 3000);
    });
```

[image: El resultado que envia mi codigo es este]

[image: Resultado deseado con los saltos de linea]

El resultado que envia mi codigo es este

Resultado deseado con los saltos de linea

Comment: por favo mira [ask].. tu codigo y errores siempre deben ir como texto

Comment: Muchas gracias. lo voy a corregir

Comment: Listo, espero que se encuentre mas entendible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te puedes fijar en la URL, `%0A` puede usarse para generar un caracter de salto de linea (0x0A). Por tanto si el pedido tiene saltos de linea puedes ajustar la siguiente linea:

```
var pedido = document.querySelector('#pedido').value.replace(/\n/g,'%0A');
```

Lo mismo para cualquier variable que desees enviar con saltos de linea.

Ahora, una solución aun mas general (no solo saltos de linea sino *cualquier caracter especial*) es usar `encodeURI()`:

```
var pedido = encodeURI(document.querySelector('#pedido').value);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURI

Comment: Muchas gracias utilic-e replaceAll ya que solo tomaba el primer \n

Comment: Tener cuidado con replaceAll() ya que es una implementacion reciente y no esta disponible aun en todos los browsers. Si utilizas `/\n/g` deberia tener el mismo efecto que replaceAll (modificador `/g` en la expresion regular reemplaza en todos las ocurrencias) https://caniuse.com/#search=replaceAll

Comment: Me genera la misma problematica si no utilizo replaceAll(), no funciona correctamente la expresion. solo desaparece `\n`

Comment: @FrankMartinez, creo que es más adecuado el uso de `encodeURI`, porque aplica a todos los caracteres especiales: espacios, saltos de línea, caracteres con tilde, etc.

Comment: @Triby De igual forma `encodeURI` no soluciona el problema.

Comment: @FrankMartinez, no incluyas la URL, ni parámetros, codifica solo el mensaje.

Comment: Es correcto solo codificando el mensaje no genera el error. Muchas gracias @Triby

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió para C# también :)